# Django-PostgresPool max poolsize

Tags: django, postgresql

Here is my setting :

```
DATABASE_POOL_ARGS = {
    'max_overflow': 3,
    'pool_size': 3,
    'recycle': 300
}
```

I set pool_size =3

But I look up the result in postgres( `SELECT sum(numbackends) FROM pg_stat_database;`  )

The number still over 3 , How can I set the connection   ??
I want to set the max to 100,And let all requests share these 100  connections to communicate with postgresql

Answer (score 0):

`pool_size` is the number of idle connections (ie at least these many will always be connected), and `max_overflow` is the maximum allowed on top of that.

So the total maximum is `pool_size + max_overflow`. You should set `pool_size` to the minimum number you think you will typically need, and `max_overflow` to `100 - pool_size`.